# How do I get rid of this box in my Word Document?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

[image]

I think it's only coincidence that the box is near a Page Break, but maybe not.  Either way, I can't move it or delete it.  If I duplicate the document, it's still there.  If I try to Copy/Paste the entire document into a new one (sans the box), the whole thing gets jacked up and I'd pretty much have to re-write it.  I don't even know what the box represents, but I assume a table, or a generated area, or perhaps some artifact of having a Table of Contents inserted.  It's not mine, it was there when I arrived, I swear!

Comment: It's a content control box. Have you tried clicking on the three dots on the left-hand side and then hitting your back space? If it won't delete after trying that, it must have some type of editing restriction.

Comment: Interesting, a restriction.  I did try that, as well as using the 3-dots to try to "cut" it, and it says `Word can't cut this content.  Please try copying it instead`.  I can google how to change restrictions, but if you know the answer, that would solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

The Content Control seems to be locked. You can check the content control’s properties, just select the control, then go to [the Developer tab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45), and click Properties. Please check if the check box is prevented from being deleted:

[image]

If so,  clear that check box, click OK. Check if it can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, Herb.  The problem is that this is the Office365 online version, which can not access a Developer Tab.  But perhaps I will try downloading this as a docx, make the change, and re-upload it.  I'll let you know if I try that.

Comment: @Suamere you need to activate the Developer tab: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45